# HTML: Image won't display

Tags: html, image

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with the code below?
The code is very simple, but as you can see at the screenshot the image won't show...
Nothing, not even borders that should be if the link is broken (though it is not broken).
So why the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnEKt.png) code is 'transparent' in this case?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta= charset="utf-8">
        <title>Display Image</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <p>
            Image:
            <img= scr="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" width="640" height="480">
           </p>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe instead of `<img=` use `<img`? Also instead of `scr` use `src`. Why do you use `<meta=`, should be `<meta`. Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/xxVRoKN?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img= scr="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" width="640" height="480">
```

`=` after `img` is causing an error. Also, not `scr` but `src`. So you want it to be

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" width="640" height="480">
```